# Deadbolt will not release key easily

Tags: locks

My car was broken into recently and its left me feeling uneasy about my security. I live in an apartment complex that is getting repaired so the traffic is heavy in and out of the building daily. The main door to my apartment is secured by deadbolt and a door knob lock only. Recently, the key to the deadbolt has not been easy to release after locking or unlocking from the outside. Is this a sign that someone has tried to break in? What should I do to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Info Security. We answer Information Security questions, not physical security questions unless it is tangential to other Info Security topics. You might call your local locksmith for their opinion with this issue.

Comment: I know it's off topic, but the answer to the question is that the tailpiece which holds the cylinder (the part you put the key into) is loose, thus snagging the key when you try to pull it out. Try pushing in on the cylinder while you pull the key out.